# Getting attribute information of multiple polygon intersected by line using QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, overlapping-features, expression, virtual-field

I have a map with 'Layer A' (polygons representing cities) and 'Layer B' (lines representing roads).

I would like to add a virtual field on my 'Layer B' table with the name of every city crossed by each road.

[image]

In this example, I would like my Road 1 attribute to tell me it crosses 'City A', 'City B', 'City C', and 'City D'.

Is this possible with a QGIS expression, within a Virtual Field?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this expression:

```
array_to_string(overlay_intersects('Layer_A', name))
```

(assuming the City names are stored in name field in the 'Layer A').

Comment: Thank you, this works as expected !

Answer (score 5):

Currently a bit "old-fashioned" approach using the [`aggregate()`](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/functions_list.html#aggregate) function:

```
aggregate(layer:='Layer_A',
          aggregate:='concatenate',
          concatenator:=',',
          expression:="name",
          filter:=intersects($geometry, geometry(@parent))
          )
```

Comment: What is the length of the road segments through these areas of cities?

Comment: A good question and I think it deserves [a new question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) (perhaps it was already asked before). However, this solution may help you: `expression:=to_string("id") || ':' || to_string(length(intersection($geometry, geometry(@parent))))` results in length for each feature separately, if sum required then `aggregate:='sum'` and  `expression:=length(intersection($geometry, geometry(@parent)))`.